# How to download file from MemoryStream response?

Tags: javascript, blob, memorystream

I responded in server-side c# a MemoryStream file and I got that in the React:

```
{status: 'success', data: {…}}
data:
__identity: null
_buffer: "UEsDBBQACAAIAE2NOlPkS..."
_capacity: 3726
_expandable: true
_exposable: true
_isOpen: true
_length: 3726
_origin: 0
_position: 3726
```

How can I download this file from the react with using blob?

Comment: If I'm not wrong you could use `file-saver` npm package

Comment: And its possible without external libraries?

Comment: I don't know I have never done this before without using any external lib.

Comment: "*I got that in the React*" - what exactly were you doing? Please show us your code. We can't tell you how to download the react output.

Comment: @AvielPalgi Anything that is possible with external libraries is also possible without them, you just have to write the code yourself.

Answer (score 0):

@bergi That's what i do in the C#:

```
  MemoryStream result = new MemoryStream();
            ExcelPackage pack = ExportMailsToExcelReactTest(embedMail, leadsList, embedDynamicForm, culture);
            pack.SaveAs(result);
            return result;
```

And in the React i do nothing, just got the response data.